# What series approaches to $\log(\log(\log(n)))$?

Tags: prime-numbers, logarithms, harmonic-analysis, euler-mascheroni-constant, prime-gaps

Background: Harmonic series approaches to $\lim_{n->\infty}\log(n)$. This gives the [Euler–Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_constant). In addition, the harmonic series summed only over the primes approaches to $\lim_{n->\infty}\log(\log(n))$. This gives the [Meissel–Mertens constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissel%E2%80%93Mertens_constant).

Question: What similar series approaches to $\lim_{n->\infty}\log(\log(\log(n)))$.

My failed attempts: I thought about **further filtering out primes to get an even slower-growing series**. For example, I only choose the paired primes (twin primes or $k$-twin primes). But then I learned that these series converge using [Brun's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brun%27s_theorem).

There ought to be someone who has thought about this problem possibly with answers. Can anyone please point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: The derivatives of $\log n$ and $\log \log n$ are $\frac{1}{n}$ (harmonic series) and $\frac{1}{n\log n}$ (prime reciprocals, b/c $p_n\sim n\log n$). So then try differentiating $\log\log\log n$. Dunno if there's any "natural" arithmetic sequence with the resulting asymptotic, though.

Comment: You missed a $\log$ in your first line.

Comment: Thanks. @jjagmath, corrected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The heuristic argument for why the sum of prime reciprocals diverges as $\log\log n$ is that we may model an integer $n$ as being "prime with probability $\frac1{\log n}$", by the prime number theorem: so its contribution to the sum of prime reciprocals is on average $\frac1{n \log n}$. Further approximating this sum by an integral, we notice that $$\int \frac{1}{x \log x}\,\mathrm dx = \log\log x + C.$$
Similarly, it is true that
$$\int \frac{1}{x \log x \log\log x}\,\mathrm dx = \log\log\log x + C,$$ so we want a sum over reciprocals where an integer $n$ has a probability of $O(\frac1{\log n\log\log n})$ of contributing to the sum.

So we could, for example, say: "Take the sum of reciprocals of all primes which have a prime number of digits." Heuristically, a number $n$ has a $\frac1{\log n}$ chance of being prime, but it has $O(\log n)$ digits, and he number of digits has an $O(\frac1{\log \log n})$ chance of being prime.

Now let's try to figure this out carefully. What is the sum of reciprocals of all prime-digit primes less than $n$?

Well, for every prime $p$ such that $10^p < n$, we have the sum of reciprocals of all primes from $10^{p-1}$ to $10^p-1$. By the Meissel–Mertens result, for sufficiently large $p$, this should contribute $(1+o(1))(\log \log 10^p - \log \log 10^{p-1})$, which simplifies to $(1+o(1))\log \frac{p}{p-1})$. As $x \to 0$, $\log(1+x) \sim x$, and we can simplify this to $(1+o(1))\frac1p$.

Therefore for each prime $p$ such that $10^p < n$, the contribution to the sum is $(1+o(1))\frac1p$, which means that the overall sum is asymptotically equal to the sum of $\frac1p$ over all $p$ up to $\log_{10} n$. By the Meissel–Mertens asymptotics again, this should be $\log\log\log n$.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer demystified the existing two examples I gave. Now it doesn't feel odd why $\log(n)$ and $\log\log(n)$ appeared in the first place. It also made me less obsessed about finding the next mysterious series. It suddenly made primes less mysterious to me too. 

Now I start to think what other types of primes occurs with similar probability as "primes which have a prime number of digits"? Maybe we can call the double-primes or two-fold primes, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You have

- $\frac{d}{dx} \log(x)=\frac1x$ so $\sum\limits_{m=1}^n\frac1m$ will be $O(\log(n))$
- $\frac{d}{dx} \log(\log(x))=\frac1{x\log(x)}$ so $\sum\limits_{m=2}^n\frac1{m\log(m)}$ will be $O(\log(\log(n)))$
- $\frac{d}{dx} \log(\log(\log(x)))=\frac1{x\log(x)\log(\log(x))}$ so $\sum\limits_{m=16}^n\frac1{m\log(m)\log(\log(m))}$ will be $O(\log(\log(\log(n))))$ at least when $n> e^{e}$

Comment: Being $O(f(x))$ is not the same that being asymptotic to $f(x)$, for example $\sum_{m=1}^n \frac{1}{m} = O(n)$. What you want are series that are either asymptotic  ( $\sim f(x)$) or at least of comparable growth ($ = \Theta (f(x))$.

Comment: @jjagmath Fair enough, though these examples will be asymptotic too (the ratios will tend to $1$ and the differences will tend to a constant)

Answer (score -1):

There is a generic way to look at this in terms of integers in residue classes.

Definitions:

1. Let $p,q$ represent primes and let $n$ be a positive integer.
2. $\pi(n)$ has its usual meaning.
3. Let $p_1, p_2,\cdots$ represent the primes starting with $2,3,\cdots$.

Let $\{a_1\}$-primes represent integers $\leq n$ that are $\not\equiv a_1 \bmod p$ ($p_1 \leq p \leq \sqrt{n}$). Slight deviation from definition but we will assume $\{0\}$-primes as the usual primes.

Let $\{a_1,a_2\}$-primes represent $\{a_1\}$-primes that are $\not\equiv a_2 \bmod p$ ($p_2 \leq p \leq \sqrt{n}$).

Let $\{a_1,a_2,a_3\}$-primes represent $\{a_1,a_2\}$-primes that are $\not\equiv a_3 \bmod p$ ($p_3 \leq p \leq \sqrt{n}$).

and so on.

The sum of the reciprocal of $\{a_1\}$-primes is $\approx \log\log(n)$

The sum of the reciprocal of $\{a_1,a_2\}$-primes is $\approx \log\log\log(n)$

The sum of the reciprocal of $\{a_1,a_2,a_3\}$-primes is $\approx \log\log\log\log(n)$ and so on. Obviously $n$ has to be sufficiently large to accommodate more logs.

ps: There are beautiful relationships between the counts of such primes as well. Happy to share if there is interest.